# Why do I need the whole 'build' folder when I run a .exe created with cx_freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, cx-freeze

I created a .exe with cx_freeze and tried sending the program to my work computer, but it didn't work unless I sent the whole 'build' folder. I understand that I need some .dll's but even if I copy those the program won't run, it'll just crash without giving me any info about why. Do I really need the whole folder or is there just something else other than the .dll's in the folder that I just need to include as well? It's sort of annoying to have to up- and download a 350MB file for a tiny program each time I make a little update. I tried just sending the only folder that I Could see had changed since last time (IIRC it was the 'tk' folder inside 'build') but that didn't work either.

Also, I want to send the program to a guy at work who uses a Macbook, are the files/folders that I need to include the same as for windows?

Comment: If the issue is the amount of files, consider to use pyinstaller, which lets you build a one-file if I recall correctly.

Comment: I think I tried it but it wasn't compatible with Python 3.6 or something

Comment: I don't think the amount of files is the main problem. Rather the amount/size of unnecessary ones that I need to send each time because I don't know which ones are actually necessary.

Comment: Oh yeah, is not supported yet, the last working build it's for 3.5